# How to use GraphQL with core SpringMVC + Hibernate App

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, graphql

I'm using the core Spring MVC and Hibernate, my app is working fine and due to some technical issues I can't migrate to SpringBoot, So is there any way by which I can use the GraphQL in my current app only without using SpringBoot.